# If I upload a new version of a javascript file to Amazon S3, should I expect browser caching problems?

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-s3, requirejs

We have a large number of people (10k+) who return to my clients' sites on a regular basis to use a web app we built, improve, and host for them.  We have been making fairly frequent backward-incompatible updates to the web app's javascript as our app has improved and evolved. During deployments, the javascript is minified and concatenated into one file, loaded in the browser by require.js, and is uploaded to and hosted on Amazon S3. The file name & url currently doesn't change at all during updates. This last week we deployed a major refactor to the web app and got a few (but not a lot) of reports back that the app stopped working for some people, particularly in firefox.  It seemed like a caching issue. We were able to see it initially in a few browsers in testing but it seemed to go away after a refresh or two.

It dawned on me that I really don't know what browser-caching ramifications deploying a new version of a javascript file (with the same name) on S3 will have and whether this situation warrants cache-busting or manipulating S3's headers or anything. Can someone help me get a handle on this? Are there actions I should be taking during deployments to ensure that browsers will immediately get the new version of a javascript file?  If not, we run the risk of the javascript and the server API being out of sync and failing, which I think happened here.

Not sure if it matters, but the site's server runs Django and the app and DB are deployed to Heroku.  Static files are deployed to S3 using S3Boto via Django's collectstatic command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends a lot on the behaviour of S3 and the headers it sends when requesting files on S3. As you experienced, browsers will show different caching behaviour - so the best option is to use unique filenames.

I would suggest to use cachebuster hashes - in this way you can be sure that the new file always gets requested by browsers and you can use long cache-lifetime headers if you host the files on your own server. 
You can for example create a MD5 hash of your minified file and append it (like `mycss-322242fadcd23.css`). Or you could use the revision number of your source control system. You have to use the cache buster in all links to this file, but you can normally easily do this in your templates where you embed your static resources. Depending on your application, you could probably use [this Django plugin](https://github.com/jaddison/django-cachebuster) that should do this work for you.